# activity switching not working without finish() method

Tags: android

My code is as shown below:

TableActivity.java

```
public class TableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_selection);
        itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        foodMenuLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.foodMenuLayout);
        drinkMenuLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drinksMenuLayout);
        tableNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tableNo);
        foodMenu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodMenu);
        drinksMenu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drinksMenu);
        tapLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tapLayout);
        foodImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foodImage);
        drinkImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drinkImage);

        getFoodTruckInfo();

        tapLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tableList = TableList.getInstance(MyCart.getInstance().getTableNo());
                tableList.setItemListener(TableActivity.this);
                tableList.setCancelable(false);
                tableList.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
            }
        });

        setFontStyle();

        foodMenuLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tableNo.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Toast.makeText(TableActivity.this, "Please select table", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    lauchItemActivity();
                }
            }
        });

        drinkMenuLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tableNo.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Toast.makeText(TableActivity.this, "Please select table", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    lauchDrinksActivity();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void lauchItemActivity() {
        FoodtruckInfo foodtruckInfo = new FoodtruckInfo();
        foodtruckInfo.setFoodTruckName(foodTruck.getFoodTruckName());
        foodtruckInfo.setFoodTruckImage(foodTruck.getFoodTruckLogo());
        foodtruckInfo.setFoodTruckId(foodTruck.getFoodTruckId());
        foodtruckInfo.setOrderStatus(foodTruck.getFoodTruckOpenStatus());
        Intent intent = new Intent(TableActivity.this, FoodTruckItemsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.FOODTRUCK_INFO, foodtruckInfo);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.IS_SEARCH, false);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.IS_DRINKS, false);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Consts.FOODTRUCK_ITEM, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) foodTruck.getFoodTruckItemList());

        startActivityForResult(intent, Consts.ITEMS_ACTIVITY);
    }


    private void lauchDrinksActivity() {
        FoodtruckInfo foodtruckInfo = new FoodtruckInfo();
        foodtruckInfo.setFoodTruckName(foodTruck.getFoodTruckName());
        foodtruckInfo.setFoodTruckImage(foodTruck.getFoodTruckLogo());
        foodtruckInfo.setFoodTruckId(foodTruck.getFoodTruckId());
        foodtruckInfo.setOrderStatus(foodTruck.getFoodTruckOpenStatus());
        Intent intent = new Intent(TableActivity.this, FoodTruckDrinksActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.FOODTRUCK_INFO, foodtruckInfo);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.IS_SEARCH, false);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.IS_DRINKS, true);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Consts.FOODTRUCK_ITEM, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) foodTruck.getFoodTruckDrinkList());
        startActivityForResult(intent, Consts.DRINKS_ACTIVITY);
    }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == Consts.ITEMS_ACTIVITY) {
                lauchDrinksActivity();
            } else if (requestCode == Consts.DRINKS_ACTIVITY) {
                lauchItemActivity();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FoodTruckItemsActivity.java

```
public class FoodTruckItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        FoodTruckItemsAdapter.OnItemClickListener, FoodTruckItemFragment.FoodTruckItemListener,
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_truck_item);

 routeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                routeToAnotherMenu();
            }
        });
    }

 private void routeToAnotherMenu() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
}
```

**FoodTruckItemsActivity.java** and **FoodTruckDrinksActivity.java** are identical. So what I want here is if I press `routeView`, it should switch from `FoodTruckItemsActivity.java` to `FoodTruckDrinksActivity.java` and vice-versa.
  For that I have written `routeToAnotherMenu()` method. Now problem here is if I do not write `finish()` inside `routeToAnotherMenu`, it does not load another activity. But if I write finish after `setResult()` then it works perfectly.

The main  reason why I do not prefer finish() inside that method because it will erase the data . So is there any way through which I can do it without writing finish() method?

Comment: Post your manifest file also

Comment: why you are using  startActivityForResult(); whereas you can call this by simple way using startActivity();?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar I want to track the result of activity

Comment: @MrugeshThaker if you do not write finish() it won't allow to go to your previous activity. Let me know one thing FoodTruckItemsActivity contains data right so you want to use that data in your TableActivity is it you want? let me know

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I have items added in FoodTruckItemActivity.java. Now if I switch from FoodTruckItemActivity.java to FoodTruckDrinkActivity.java and then again switch from FoodTruckDrinkActivity.java to FoodTruckItemsActivity.java  the I should see those items added in FoodTruckItemActivity.java

Comment: Okey This is very simple solution I will post the answer.

Comment: @MrugeshThaker see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setResult() should be used before starting another activity, or if you want the activity that launched this activity to collect the result after you exit (calling finish).[Here is a link to docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

I could imagine 2 ways for the result you want to achieve:

1)Decouple the "data" you want to mantain after the finish() (for example, into a singleton) from the current activity.
If FoodTruckItemsActivity.java and FoodTruckDrinksActivity.java are almost identical, they should inherite from a common parent, so you will ease the job.
It's better also because "TableActivity" starts always a new intent every time, so it is useless to not call the finish.

2)You could also change approach converting FoodTruckItemsActivity and FoodTruckDrinksActivity to Fragments, swapping them into a fragment container of "TableActivity" and sharing the data into the activity.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for [`onActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)):

> Called when an activity you launched exits (...)

Just setting the result won't cause the method to be called.

If you want to switch freely between screens, maybe you should consider using Fragments?

Answer (score 1):

In Your case **FoodTruckItemActivity** is Common activity from where you open your **FoodTruckDrinkActivity**.

Now, For E.g declare the ArrayList in TableActivity to store all your selected data in that arrayList.

Now When you startActivityForResult() for FoodTruckItemsActivity. In FoodTruckItemsActivity declare the ArrayList for adding the data. Now when you route to another menu write this.

```
Intent intent=new Intent();  
intent.putStringArrayList("FOODITEMLIST", myItemList);  
setResult(intent);  
finish();
```

Now In your Table activity the result comes here in onActivityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Consts.ITEMS_ACTIVITY) {
            // Get the arraylist and add that list in Table Activity Main ArrayList 
            // which we declare earlier in Table Activity.
            lauchDrinksActivity();
        } else if (requestCode == Consts.DRINKS_ACTIVITY) {
            lauchItemActivity();
        }
    }
}
```